# Android ListView LazyAdapter for Fragment

Tags: java, android, listview, fragment, listadapter

I extends my App for Tablet-Design and use Fragments.

The MainActivity:

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
         FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager()
         .beginTransaction();
         transaction.add(R.id.fragmentcontainer1, new list());
         transaction.commit();
    }
}
```

The List Fragment with XML Loader and LazyAdapter:

```
public class lst extends Fragment {

    String URL = "URL HERE";
    static final String KEY_COUPON = "coupon"; // parent node
    static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private boolean onCreateRunned = false;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list;

    ListView list;
    LazyAdapter adapter;

    @Override
      public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
              Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list,
                container, false); 



        list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
        String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL);
        Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml);

        NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_COUPON);
        for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
            map.put(KEY_ID, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ID));
            list.add(map);
        }

        list=(ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list);

        adapter= new LazyAdapter(getActivity(), list);        
        list.setAdapter(adapter);

        return view;


    }   

}
```

and the LazyAdapter

```
    public class LazyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Activity activity;
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
    public ImageLoader imageLoader; 


    public LazyAdapter(Context appContext, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d) {
        activity = (Activity) appContext;
        data=d;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        imageLoader=new ImageLoader(activity);
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi=convertView;
        if(convertView==null)


            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);

       // do something here

        return vi;
    }
}
```

Adn the error is:

```
01-29 16:42:14.775: E/AndroidRuntime(2057): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-29 16:42:14.775: E/AndroidRuntime(2057): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.newcouponstablet/com.example.newcouponstablet.MainActivity}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
01-29 16:42:14.775: E/AndroidRuntime(2057):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
01-29 16:42:14.775: E/AndroidRuntime(2057):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
01-29 16:42:14.775: E/AndroidRuntime(2057):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
01-29 16:42:14.775: E/AndroidRuntime(2057):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
01-29 16:42:14.775: E/AndroidRuntime(2057):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-29 16:42:14.775: E/AndroidRuntime(2057):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-29 16:42:14.775: E/AndroidRuntime(2057):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
01-29 16:42:14.775: E/AndroidRuntime(2057):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-29 16:42:14.775: E/AndroidRuntime(2057):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-29 16:42:14.775: E/AndroidRuntime(2057):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
01-29 16:42:14.775: E/AndroidRuntime(2057):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
01-29 16:42:14.775: E/AndroidRuntime(2057):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-29 16:42:14.775: E/AndroidRuntime(2057): Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
01-29 16:42:14.775: E/AndroidRuntime(2057):     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1117)
01-29 16:42:14.775: E/AndroidRuntime(2057):     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:84)
01-29 16:42:14.775: E/AndroidRuntime(2057):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:127)
01-29 16:42:14.775: E/AndroidRuntime(2057):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
01-29 16:42:14.775: E/AndroidRuntime(2057):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
01-29 16:42:14.775: E/AndroidRuntime(2057):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:459)
01-29 16:42:14.775: E/AndroidRuntime(2057):     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:842)
01-29 16:42:14.775: E/AndroidRuntime(2057):     at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:119)
01-29 16:42:14.775: E/AndroidRuntime(2057):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:144)
01-29 16:42:14.775: E/AndroidRuntime(2057):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
01-29 16:42:14.775: E/AndroidRuntime(2057):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
01-29 16:42:14.775: E/AndroidRuntime(2057):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
01-29 16:42:14.775: E/AndroidRuntime(2057):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
01-29 16:42:14.775: E/AndroidRuntime(2057):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
01-29 16:42:14.775: E/AndroidRuntime(2057):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
01-29 16:42:14.775: E/AndroidRuntime(2057):     at com.example.newcouponstablet.XMLParser.getXmlFromUrl(XMLParser.java:45)
01-29 16:42:14.775: E/AndroidRuntime(2057):     at com.example.newcouponstablet.list.onCreateView(list.java:46)
01-29 16:42:14.775: E/AndroidRuntime(2057):     at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1695)
01-29 16:42:14.775: E/AndroidRuntime(2057):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:885)
01-29 16:42:14.775: E/AndroidRuntime(2057):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1057)
01-29 16:42:14.775: E/AndroidRuntime(2057):     at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
01-29 16:42:14.775: E/AndroidRuntime(2057):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1435)
01-29 16:42:14.775: E/AndroidRuntime(2057):     at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5113)
01-29 16:42:14.775: E/AndroidRuntime(2057):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2153)
```

I hope anybody can help me to understand it.

Comment: As i see it mutch better use same names for fields :)
Map:list VIew:list

Comment: cant make that: dublicate name error

Comment: No in your paste is like that i am just joking about it :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class lst extends Fragment {

    String URL = "URL HERE";
    static final String KEY_COUPON = "coupon"; // parent node
    static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private boolean onCreateRunned = false;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list;

    ListView list;
    LazyAdapter adapter;

    @Override
      public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
              Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list,
                container, false); 



        list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        new Thread(new Runnable(){
        public void run() {

        XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
        String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL);
        Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml);

        NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_COUPON);
        for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
            map.put(KEY_ID, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ID));
            list.add(map);
        }

        //Maybe this must activity.runOnUiThread(...     
        list=(ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list);

        adapter= new LazyAdapter(getActivity(), list);        
        list.setAdapter(adapter);

        }}).start()


        return view;


    }   

}
```

Comment: With this code i got the error: 01-29 20:12:57.535: E/AndroidRuntime(4284): android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

Comment: runonuithread(new Runnable(){ public void run()
{
list=(ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list);

        adapter= new LazyAdapter(getActivity(), list);        
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
}})

Answer (score 0):

> Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

=> This occurs whennever you make/implement long running tasks on main thread itself

To avoid this, either you can implement threading (or **AsyncTask**) or include below line before making long running tasks inside onCreate() method:

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.
ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

Comment: No way. You will freeze your application. All longwork code have to be in separate thread. Because you will lose control over your application when main thread are busy and Android will kill your app.